# Filtering by list item

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there any way I could show list items depending on logged user?

I'm trying with content query and login fiedl on my list but I can't make it work.

Really apreciate your answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to display the items in a Content Query Web Part:
To be able to filter for the current user, you should create a custom CAML query with a `Where` clause like this one:

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='InternalNameOfYourPersonField' />
        <Value Type='Integer'><UserID/></Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

Then you can use the CAML query in the `QueryOverride` of the Content Query Web Part as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa981241.aspx).

If you would like to use the standard list views (List View Web Part), then simply create a new view and filter for the field value [Me] (or the corresponding language specific value depending on the culture of your SharePoint site). See a detailed description [here](http://sharepointsolutions.com/sharepoint-help/blog/2013/10/sharepoint-library-views-and-list-views/).